# Typescript: define class and its methods in separate files

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to declare a class in one file and define its methods in separate files?

I have some classes with **a lot** of methods and it would be great if I could spread them out a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** Typescript doesn't support splitting up a class definition into several files.

**Workaround**: You could define an interface containing members for the class, and two different classes implementing that interface. Then mixin properties from one class to the other, to make a combined class. For example:

**LargeClass.a.ts**

```
interface LargeClass {
   methodA(): string;
   methodB(): string;
}

class LargeA implements LargeClass {
   methodA: () => string; // not implemented, needed since otherwise we don't extend LargeClass
   methodB() {
     return "Hello world";
   }
}
```

**LargeClass.b.ts**

```
class LargeB implements LargeClass {
   methodA() {
     return "Foo";
   }
   methodB: () => string; // not implemented, needed since otherwise we don't extend LargeClass
}
```

**Usage.ts**

```
// Using underscore's extend to copy implementation from A to B
var c:LargeClass = _.extend(new LargeA(), new LargeB());

// Manually mixing in a to b
var a = new LargeA();
var b:LargeClass = new LargeB();
for (var prop in a) {
    b[prop]=a[prop];
}
```

This won't work if you need constructors for the class, though. And really it's suboptimal... Workaround none the less :)

Oh, by the way, this works because typescript doesn't emit unitialised property/field type declarations for classes--it only uses them for type checking.

I also realise that you can do this without interfaces and just the class construct in a prettier way... I'll leave how to do that as an exercise to readers for now...

Comment: Ok, so let's say that myclass.ts contains the declaration of MyClass. Now I create a second file and put the following at the top:

///<reference path='./myclass.ts' />

How do I proceed? What's the syntax to define the methods of MyClass? In C++, for example, I'd add MyClass:: before the method's definition.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you--but if you're thinking that you need a header-file for defining classes (As in C++), you don't. To use definitions (Classes, interfaces etc.) from myclass.ts in secondfile.ts, it should 'just work' with the typescript reference tag on top. Types will however be declared in the global namespace and thus, may clash, so you should take care with that. Typescript provides a module system and integration with CommonJS or AMD-module loaders for this scenario.

Comment: Yeah I think we're not talking about the same thing: I have a class representing a graphics device with several dozen methods which, by design, cannot be split into several classes. I would like to be able to define the class along with its member variables in one file and some method definitions in another file:

file 1:

class GraphicsEngine() { ... }

file 2:

GraphicsEngine.renderStuff() { ... }
GraphicsEngine.renderSomeOtherStuff() { ... } etc.

Comment: I see. I don't think typescript natively supports this via the class-type, but you could, for the sake of unified type-checking, declare an interface containing all the member type definitions, and have the two class-objects in each file implement the interface. I'll extend my answer with an example.

Comment: I should however note that this isn't really good design. A large class representing a graphics device sounds like something more suited for an interface in the first place...

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to explain that in this answer. It's from underscore.js, can be found here: http://underscorejs.org/#extend. It merely copies properties from a to b.

Comment: This problem exists for abstract classes as well I guess? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690703/index-d-ts-when-creating-a-nativescript-plugin/57736983#57736983

Answer (score 8):

you can import your functions from other files than the class itself

here is the example of the class file:

```
import {func1, func2, func3} from "./functions"

class MyClass {
   public foo: string = "bar"
   public func1 = func1.bind(this)
   public func2 = func2.bind(this)
   public func3 = func3.bind(this)
}
```

Here is the example of one function file:

```
import {MyClass} from "./MyClass"

export function func1(this: MyClass, param1: any, param2: any){
   console.log(this.foo)
   ...
}
```

**Important note:** make sure that every exported function is not an arrow function because you can't do bind(this) on an arrow function

Comment: Works also with private class-members when they have the [`protected` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected) set.

Comment: is this still working/recommended in 2023 typescript?

Comment: it seems to work without the `bind(this)` part

Comment: do we still need the `public` for each method?