# index.d.ts when creating a NativeScript plugin?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, typescript-typings

I have recently started to make a plugin in NativeScript - following the [documention](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins). And I made some successfull runs with `npm run demo.ios` in the src folder.

However when starting to build the actual plugin I intended on - I am encountering the following error:

> file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js:179:0 JS ERROR Error: Building UI from XML. @app-root.xml:1:1
>   undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.prototype')

I have set up an extension method onto `ViewBase` in my `myplugin.common.ts` file that I attempt to call from the demo application

The problem could lie in the `index.d.ts` I believe. According the docs the `myplugin.ios.d.ts` and `myplugin.android.d.ts` files should be copied in there or defined manually. I am attempting to copy the `myplugin.common.d.ts` file content in there instead. Is that valid?

I have also noticed two runs seem to be necceseray - since the first run generates the `...d.ts.` Of which content then has to copied into `index.d.ts`.

---

some code...

myplugin.common.ts

```
declare module "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base" {
  interface ViewBase {
    myExenstionMethod(myNumber: number): void;
  }
}
ViewBase.prototype.myExenstionMethod = function(myNumber: number) {
  console.log("myNumber: " + myNumber);
}
```

and `index.d.ts` (copied from `myplugin.common.d.ts`):

```
declare module "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base" {
    interface ViewBase {
        myExenstionMethod(myNumber: number): void;
    }
}
```

It is shown in the demo project:

[image]

And the error comes from simply importing the extension method from the plugin in my demo project:

```
import "nativescript-myplugin";
```

---

**Note**

I created a new plugin project - only adding the extension method and it worked. So there was something else in the original plugin project that caused the error. Adding `declare module` in `index.d.ts` was not needed.

---

**Hitting it again**

with the same error as before - when instantiating myplugin.ios.ts/myplugin.android.ts - myplugin class - from inside `myplugin.common.ts`. I initially thought about creating a platform specific singleton instance to interact with in `.common.ts` - but that does not seem to work?

```
import { Gestures as iOSGestures} from "./gestures.ios";
import {Gestures as AndroidGestures} from "./gestures.android";

export abstract class Common extends Observable {
  private static _instance = null;

  static instance(os: string): Common {
    if(Common._instance == null) {
      /* crash from instantiating iOSGestures or AndroidGestures */
      this._instance = os == "iOS" ? new iOSGestures() : new AndroidGestures();
    }
    return Common._instance;
  }
  abstract _attach(viewBase: ViewBase, gesture: string): void;
}
```

What is strange is that that particular code is never called from anywhere yet. And commenting out that line I can create that error by simply having dead code containing the instantiation:

```
// still inside .common.ts
import { Gestures } from "./gestures.android";

const object = {
  methodInFile()  {
    const g = new Gestures() // <--
  }
}
```

Here is the android.ts:

```
export class Gestures extends Common {
    _attach(viewBase: ViewBase, gesture: string): void {
        console.log("_attach android");
        if(gesture == touch.down) {

        }
    }
}
```

It could be some sort of conflict with the index.d.ts?:

```
import { Common } from './gestures.common';
export declare class Gestures extends Common {
  // define your typings manually
  // or..
  // take the ios or android .d.ts files and copy/paste them here
}
```

This my first time attempting to build a plugin NativeScript - so I might be setting things completely wrong. I hope to provide my plugin as an extension method on `ViewBase` though - and the extension method defined in common.ts is called successfully.

---

```
// inside common.ts
export class Gestures extends Common {
  _attach(): void {
      console.log("_attach ios");
  }
}
const object = {
  methodInFile()  {
    const g = new Gestures() // <--
  }
}
```

... works.

But when the class is imported from another file, having `new Gestures()` - causes the crash as mentioned. It neither works creating a new file - `ios.common.ts`. So it could be that `npm run demo.ios` is generating faulty js files on build? I also removed the content of `index.d.ts` completely - so it can't involved causing the error.

---

Making the `common.ts` an interface - that gets implemented in `.ios.ts` and `android.ts`. I encountered a new error;

> file:///app/home/home-page.ts:17:27 JS ERROR TypeError: page.addGestureHandler is not a function. (In 'page.addGestureHandler("hello")', 'page.addGestureHandler' is undefined)

My conclusion so far is that I **can't have Common as an abstract class or interface** - and instantiate `ios.ts` and `android.ts` as singletons. The class extending abstract Common - or implementing interface Common - must be in the same file as (common.ts).  <s>This can be related to the fact I am using an extension method as entry point into the plugin.</s>

Comment: TypeScript declarations (`*.d.ts`) are just for the sake of IntelliSense support with your IDE. Hence there is nothing called valid or invalid as long you export right definitions you want to expose. Most plugins will just export `index.d.ts` that will usually expose everything from `*-common.ts`.

Comment: If you are extending `ViewBase` then your declarations doesn't look quite right to me. For example you may take a look at [camara-plus plugin](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus/blob/master/src/index.d.ts), the base class is extended to add new methods.

Comment: Note I am adding an extension method to viewbase. Not extending the viewbase class.

Comment: Understood, thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @Manoj Do you know if there is any way to stop `npm run demo.ios`/`npm run demo.android` from generating `d.ts`, `.js` and `.js.map` files?

Comment: I think am hitting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706290/typescript-define-class-and-its-methods-in-separate-files. I can't have abstract class/interface in one file and implement it in another file?

Comment: Yes, you can. The thread also mentions the same. You can have a abstract class in a different file and implement the same in another file.

Comment: I see. Indeed. After renaming the platform implementation files. And moving the extension method out of `common.ts` I can in fact have my abstract class in separate file from the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript declarations `(*.d.ts)` are just for the sake of IntelliSense support with your IDE. Hence there is nothing called valid or invalid as long you export right definitions you want to expose. Most plugins will just export `index.d.ts` that will usually expose everything from `*-common.ts`.

**Update:**

In order to prevent generating `.d.ts` and `.js.map` files, you will set `declaration` & `sourceMap` flags in `src/tsconfig.json` to `false`.

You can not avoid `.js` files, that's the only sole reason of using TypeScript compiler (Converting TS to JS). While publishing your plugin or using it in demo app, `.js` files are the ones actually used.

Between, without `sourceMap` debugging may be difficult for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to set up the plugin in a correct and satisfying manner

The two main point are (if using extension method as entry point):

```
declare module "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base" {
    interface ViewBase {
        addGestureHandler(gesture: string): void;
    }
}
ViewBase.prototype.addGestureHandler = function(gesture: string) {
    console.log("addGestureHandler: " + gesture);
    // then calling platform specific singleton
}
```

... has to defined in inside a **separate file** from `myplugin.common.ts`. I call it `myplugin.ts`.

Also with this set up. `myplugin.ios.ts` and `myplugin.android.ts` has to **removed**. Create new files: `ios.impl.ts` and `android.impl.ts`. The `common.ts` then ends up containing the abstract class or interface.

---

So in the demo application home-page.ts the usage of the plugin becomes like so:

```
import "nativescript-gestures"; // available only by having a common.ts file src folder in the plugin

import { NavigatedData, Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { HomeViewModel } from "./home-view-model";

export function onNavigatingTo(args: NavigatedData) {
    const page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
    page.addGestureHandler("hello"); // <-- addGestureHandler extension method
}
```